# Android GCM Unauthorized 401 error with PHP

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Recently my GCM push message notification didn't work anymore.
I didn't change anything, in my Google API Console, I've registred the IPV6 of my dedicated server if the whitelist IP address.

But when I try to reach GCM service I always get an error :

> Unauthorized
>
> Error 401

Also tried with IPV4 without success...

I've tried the same script on my own computer and everything works smooth ...

Any idea would be very appreciate :)

Thanks for your help

Comment: i got the same problem...got any solution??please help me..

Comment: remove all ips, that's the only solution I got for now

Comment: i have like this in my google api console Referers: Any referer allowed . But still getting the same error.

Comment: That's not the same problem than me so ... That's because you have used the Browser Apps key instead of Server Apps key I think.

Comment: anyway i created new project with new api key it worked...don't know what happened...thanks.

Comment: Any news on this - a new project is no option - because of running application. it stopped working?

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the server IP address in the whitelist ip addresses in google api console for GCM.

Edit:
you must use Key for server apps (with IP locking) instead of browser key.

Comment: What did you call "server ID" ?? If you mean IP, my IPV6 and IPV4 are already referenced in the whitelist IP addresses in google api console

Comment: exactly!! also u need to use server apps key, see edited answer

Comment: That's what I've done, I've succeded for now by removing all ips to get the "Any IP allowed" ... not the best ...

Comment: Sorry but removing IP is for me a temporary solution, set IP on Google API Console in Server APPS still doesn't work ...

Comment: did you used server apps key?

Comment: Of course I do ! set my IPV6 IP -> service stop working, remove IP -> service works properly.

Answer (score 2):

i have had the same issue for 1 whole day ! but silly me...
in your Dev console>APIs & auth > make sure your "google cloud messaging for android" is ON !
That was my mistake.
And also first test by allowing all IPs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What resolved it for me was registering my public ip, waiting for a few minutes and then refreshing the google api console page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and ended up adding "0::0/0" to my whitelist ip addresses.  This fixed the problem for me.  Though a better solution would be to get a real IPV6 to use for the server.

Comment: where can you do that? I can't find in Google Console

Comment: @MaicolBen it's been a while since I've done this.  But I think it's after you click on "Create new Server Key".