# GCM 401 error android and php

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an Android application with PHP as back-end.

Here I need to use Google Cloud Messaging feature of Google.

Firstly I have tested this application on local host (in xamp server for PHP server) and its work very fine. But when I implement it using real server, I always get **401 unauthorized** error at PHP side.

I think the problem resides at configuring server ip addresses on Google developer console.

For testing on local host, I have put **0.0.0.0/0** as mention on Developers site and its work fine.

For real server I have put my **server public ip** there and I started getting this error.

So what would I need to put there? And if its right then from where the shit I am getting that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try making field blank(not put any ip address) while generating server key? It's working for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the server IP address in the whitelist ip addresses in google api console for GCM.

Edit: you must use Key for server apps (with IP locking) instead of browser key.

Referred from here: [[Android GCM Unauthorized 401 error with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164354/android-gcm-unauthorized-401-error-with-php][1])

Comment: i have read that answer allready.

will you please explain me how to put server IP address in the whitelist ip addresses ?
And "Edit: you must use Key for server apps (with IP locking) instead of browser key."